# Read and replace C #ifndef/#endif enclosure with Python

Tags: python, parsing

I wanted to replace the old inclusion guard macros with a `#pragma once` in a huge project.

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class foo
{
};

#endif
```

I wonder, what could be a reliable strategy to replace the `#ifndef #define #endif` block? Are regular expressions still suitable for this? I feel that parsing the top (for the `#define`) and the bottom (for the `#endif`) of the header is maybe error prone in case of template header files and similar stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex

```
import re

s = '''
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class foo
{
  // ensure regex is greedy
#ifndef A
#define A
#endif
};

#endif'''

regexpr = re.compile(r'#ifndef [A-Za-z_]+\s+#define [A-Za-z_]+\s+(.*)\s+#endif',
                   re.DOTALL)

newf = '#pragma once\n\n{}'.format(regexpr.search(s).group(1))
```

outputs

```
#pragma once

class foo
{
  // ensure regex is greedy
#ifndef A
#define A
#endif
};
```

Comment: There is btw a typo regexpr != rexpr. Seems to work well.

Comment: @dgrat fixed :)